# Maximization version of Travelling Salesman where you don't have to go to certain nodes and can go over multiple paths?

Tags: algorithm, graph

To be concrete, I want to maximize my profit. I start at a prefixed node (headquarters), and gain some profit every time I go to a different node (for a particular node, I can only get this profit once but I can travel there as many times as I like). But to get to any node, I pay some cost (to travel along each path). I want to maximize my earning and return to headquarters. I am allowed to not go to some nodes if that causes my earning to be maximum (because of the cost to get there). I can also go over paths multiple times on my route.
Is there a version of the TSP like this? Is it solvable? (I was thinking Warshall's might be applicable).

Comment: If you can make a profit at any one node, just keep going back there over and over again, thus making total profit infinite.

Comment: Okay sorry I should have clarified: you can only get the profit once, but you can keep visiting as many times as you like.

Comment: Get the profit once but pay the toll every time you go down a road? That's unfair.

Comment: This looks essentially like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's some untested pseudo code that attempts to solve this problem. You just have to keep trying nodes until a profit constraint is reached.

```
Home = StartNode
Result = [Home]
MaxProfit = 0

Sub Solve(last, currentProfit, path, visitedSet)
  If currentProfit + graph.Nodes.Except(visitedSet).Sum(n => n.Profit) <= MaxProfit Then
    Return
  End If
  If node == Home AndAlso currentProfit > MaxProfit Then
    Result = path
    MaxProfit = currentProfit
  End If
  For Each node In graph.Nodes
    edge = graph.Edges.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Has(last) && e.Has(node))
    If edge Then
      profit = -edge.Cost
      If Not visitedSet.Contains(node) Then
        profit += node.Profit
      End If
      Solve(node, currentProfit + profit, path.Copy().Add(node), visitedSet.Copy().Add(node))
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Call Solve(Home, 0, [Home], [])
```

**EDIT** One improvement might be to precalculate the cheapest route home from every node and use that to refine the profit constraint.